# Extract operating system version with osversion

Tags: c#

I created a small program that extracts my operating system version with OSVERSIONINFO APIs.
My problem is that when I run the program on a Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB PC it turns out to be VER_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS instead of VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE.

```
Scada.Windows.API.OSVERSIONINFO osvi2 = new Scada.Windows.API.OSVERSIONINFO();
osvi2.dwOSVersionInfoSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Scada.Windows.API.OSVERSIONINFO));
Scada.Windows.API.GetVersionEx(ref osvi2);
String osname = String.Empty;
        if (osvi2.dwPlatformId == VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT)
        {
            if (osvi2.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
            {
                if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 0)
                    osname = "Windows 2000";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 1)
                    osname = "Windows XP";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 2)
                    osname = "Windows XP x64 PRO";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 0)
                    osname = "Windows VISTA";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 1)
                    osname = "Windows 7";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 2)
                    osname = "Windows 8";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 3)
                    osname = "Windows 8.1";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 10 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 0)
                    osname = "Windows 10";
            }
            else if (osvi2.wProductType == VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER ||
                osvi2.wProductType == VER_NT_SERVER)
            {
                if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 2)
                    osname = "Windows Server 2003";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 0)
                    osname = "Windows Server 2008";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 1)
                    osname = "Windows Server 2008 R2";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 2)
                    osname = "Windows Server 2012";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 3)
                    osname = "Windows Server 2012 R2";
                else if (osvi2.dwMajorVersion == 10 && osvi2.dwMinorVersion == 0)
                    osname = "Windows Server 2010";
            }
        }
        osname += " ";

        Console.WriteLine(osname);
        //==================================================================

        switch (osvi2.wSuiteMask.ToString())
        {
            case "4":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_BACKOFFICE";
                break;
            case "1024":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_BLADE";
                break;
            case "16384":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_COMPUTE_SERVER";
                break;
            case "128":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_DATACENTER";
                break;
            case "2":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE";
                break;
            case "64":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_EMBEDDEDNT";
                break;
            case "512":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_PERSONAL";
                break;
            case "256":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS";
                break;
            case "1":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_SMALLBUSINESS";
                break;
            case "32":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_SMALLBUSINESS_RESTRICTED";
                break;
            case "8192":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_STORAGE_SERVER";
                break;
            case "16":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_TERMINAL";
                break;
            case "32768":
                txt_Edition.Text = "VER_SUITE_WH_SERVER";
                break;
        }
```

Do you have any advice on how to extract OS versions?
I've also tried using this code

```
var reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");

            string productName = (string)reg.GetValue("ProductName");

            txt_PorductName.Text = productName;
```

but I would rather use APIs.

Comment: Why would you expect it to return ENTERPRISE? Why do you think SINGLEUSERTS is wrong? Why are you processing what is effectively a flags enumeration as if it should have a single value?

Comment: I do not understand this should have to lower my reputation. If I ask for help is because I'm not expert and so I ask a question on the forum.
I thought it was wrong and I should return it to ENTERPRISE. If you tell me it's just my code then I asked what a way to figure out if I'm in front of an OS Enterprise.

Comment: Can you explain, based on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833(v=vs.85).aspx) why you think you *should* get `VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE` ?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but only because it is a Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Microsoft has given up on properly labeling their SKUs.  They got fed-up with having to test tens of thousands of programs every single time they created a new one.  And they created a *lot* of new ones as part of their UWP strategy.   The kind of test that is necessary when a programmer disables a feature of his program when it runs on the "wrong" OS.  Almost always broken because such code can't know the "next version" and can't know that Microsoft did a lot of work to keep it compatible.  Such a program requires an appcompat shim that lies about the version.  Now they all have it.